# How can I run the executable file created by Code::Blocks on Ubuntu?

Tags: c++, command-line, terminal, ubuntu-12.04, codeblocks

I have written a small program just like `hello the world`, everything was OK when I run it within the Code::Blocks IDE. But I couldn't run the file created outside Code::Blocks. In it's `Properties`, I found its type being `executable(application/x-executable)`.

And another question I have is, why is the file created by Code::Blocks not of the `.exe` type. Of course, I don't want to run the file on Ubuntu like on Windows. And I think there is another way to compile and debug programs on Ubuntu, that's a better, hehe. Please help me! thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You see, on Ubuntu, and Linux, executables have no extension (unlike Windows, which uses `.exe` and `.com`). And there's another thing: To run a file, the executable bit must be set. So, to execute the application (I'm assuming you're using Unity), open the dash, and search for "Terminal". Start the first result. Here, you'll be in a console, where you can type commands for the system. The folder is starts in is your home directory. First, use the `cd` command to get to that directory:

```
cd Documents/Programing/HelloWorld/
```

Then execute the program like this:

```
./hello
```

(`hello` replaces with the file name of your program). If this doesn't work with an error message about permissions, execute this first:

```
chmod +x hello
```

Comment: @Growth7: See previous comment, but also, the second thing is something you might have to execute before the first, not just on it's own.

Comment: This answer helped me a lot with CodeBlocks 10.05 on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

Comment: The output path may vary depending on you configuration. Inspect the IDE settings for the actual path. (Maybe this note could be added to the answer.)

Answer (score 0):

After some research, I came to the conclusion that [Linuxios answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11218128/2932052) can be more focused.

- You run the program from within the IDE, that means, that the executable flag was set, I assume 
   (I tried the same and found it already set by CodeBlocks, as visible in the property dialog)
- You navigated properly to the folder that contained the program, I assume.
- **The only you missed** is [**your PATH** being applied](https://askubuntu.com/a/320657/213118) from the command shell to search for executable commands. And this PATH didn't contain the current folder.

Prefixing the program with `./` will override the path search.